# Bootstrapped UTF-8 site displays well in Chrome & FF, but Turkish characters become weird in only IE11

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, utf-8

All my Turkish character web projects run on UTF-8 MySQL databases successfully ever since. They all display correctly in all major browsers including IE. Bootstrapping my projects brought in problems in IE. Whenever I include the newly downloaded, unmodified "bootstrap.min.css" file (no other modifications) in my HTML file, Turkish characters become weird in only IE11. They still display well in Chrome & FF. Since the unmodified "bootstrap.min.css" file is ASCII, I've opened it with Notepad++ and modified it as UTF-8 without BOM. It fails again in IE11 while displaying correctly in Chrome & FF. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly does "weird" look like?!

Comment: IE11: All Latin based characters display well but Turkish characters like ü, ö, ç, ı are replaced by non alphanumeric characters. Interestingly, when I ever copy them with mouse selection and paste into Notepad, the characters pasted are the expected Turkish characters. I've examined the IE11's encoding being Unicode (UTF-8) with direction LTR.

Comment: Show a screenshot! It's probably just a *font* problem.

Comment: deceze, I should thank you. I created a blank UTF-8 HTML file, pasted the Turkish text and copied bootstrap's style body { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;} and displayed it with IE showing still weird characters. I changed the order of the fonts to Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif AND NOW IE DISPLAYS THE TEXT WITH ARIAL PERFECTLY. So someone should know that utf-8 Turkish characters CAN NOT be displayed in IE with the "Helvetica Neue" and Helvetica fonts. Who should be contacted for this bug? Or is this a bug? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user14736 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13823

Answer (score 0):

I created a blank UTF-8 HTML file, pasted the Turkish text and copied bootstrap's style body { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;} and IE still shows weird characters for the Turkish ones.

I changed the order of the fonts in CSS to Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif and now IE is okay with the Turkish caharacters.

In summary this is just a font problem. Just change the order of the fonts in your bootstrap CSS file or better, replace them with some standard fonts like Arial, Helvetica etc.